# Could not deduce (Eq i) arising from the literal ‘0’

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to Haskell and trying to write a function that similar to `take`, i.e. return a specified number of items from the specified list. My code is as following:

```
take' :: (Num i, Ord a) => i -> [a] -> [a]
take' 0 _ = []
take' _ [] = []
take' n (x:xs) = x : take' (n - 1) xs
```

However, when I try to compile it, I receive the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Eq i) arising from the literal ‘0’
from the context (Num i, Ord a)
  bound by the type signature for
             take' :: (Num i, Ord a) => i -> [a] -> [a]
  at recursion.hs:1:10-42
Possible fix:
  add (Eq i) to the context of
    the type signature for take' :: (Num i, Ord a) => i -> [a] -> [a]
In the pattern: 0
In an equation for ‘take'’: take' 0 _ = []
```

I think that the error is caused as Haskell is not able to recognise 0 as a member of class type Num, but I'm not sure. Can anyone explain the error to me and show me how to fix it.

Comment: You want `take' :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: @Alec: I think he wants `take' :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> [b] -> [b]` :)

Comment: You need to add an `Eq` constraint for `i`: `(Num i, Eq i, Ord a) => i -> [a] -> [a]` although it's not clear what the `Ord` constraint on `a` is for.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes! Thank you.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It works!!! Thanks.

Comment: @Lee You're right, I don't need the Ord constraint. Thanks.

Comment: @LongThai: actually you do not need to specify the type signature. Haskell can derive that automatically. Furthermore in `ghci`, you can use `:t take'` to obtain the type signature of that function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pattern matches against literal numbers desugar to equality checks. So

```
take' 0 _ = []
```

becomes

```
take' x _ | x == 0 = []
```

(where `x` is chosen to be a variable not mentioned anywhere else in the clause). So to support this pattern, you need the number of things to take not just to be a `Num` but also to support `(==)`! That's what this part of the error says:

```
Could not deduce (Eq i) arising from the literal ‘0’
In the pattern: 0
In an equation for ‘take'’: take' 0 _ = []
```

You can just take the fix that GHC suggests in the error:

```
Possible fix:
  add (Eq i) to the context of
    the type signature for take' :: (Num i, Ord a) => i -> [a] -> [a]
```

Thus:

```
take' :: (Eq i, Num i, Ord a) => i -> [a] -> [a]
```

Afterwards you can think about whether the `Ord a` constraint is needed at all. =)